# C# — Handle different possible values in the same key from external HTTP call

Tags: c#, .net, http, .net-core

What's the correct way of handling a result with possible different types for the same key?

Example HTTP call JSON response:

```
[
  {
    "code": 200,
    "body": {
      "id": "foo",
      "status": "paused", ← this is a string
      ...more properties of MyType (id and status are properties of MyTypem as well)
    }
  },
  {
    "code": 404,
    "body": {
      "id" "bar",
      "status": 404, ← this is a number
      ...more properties of a small but different object
    }
  }
]
```

I tried using `object` or `dynamic` for either the whole `body` property or only the `status` but always had parsing errors when attempting to transform or cast to `MyType`.

I don't really care about elements with status code other than 200 in the list so I filtering them out with a LINQ Where but I keep getting different type of errors.

This is an example of one of the things I tried:

```
var response = await client.GetAsync("https://api.com");
try
{
  var str = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
  {
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
    MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore
  };
  var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(str, settings);
  return results.Where(x => x.code == 200).Select(x => (MyType)x.body).ToList();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  Log.Error($"There was an error parsing: {ex}");
}
```

Is there any correct way of doing this at runtime?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserialize JSON which can have different objects under same property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37054003/deserialize-json-which-can-have-different-objects-under-same-property-name)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50010433/json-net-different-json-schemas-for-a-single-property if you struggle to read/apply the VB in that one